# How to send in a get a hexadecimal color?

Tags: php

For example: `index.php?color=#c2c2c2`

```
echo $_GET['color'];
```

This possibly will not work, so how?

Comment: maybe `index.php?color=c2c2c2` and `echo '#' . $_GET['color'];` ?

Comment: what if color can be as a name as well?

Comment: @Kamil And don't forget about XSS!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

URL encode what you send in. `#`, when url encoded, is `%23`.

On the receiving side, you just need to do:

```
$color = urldecode($_GET['color']);
```

To URL encode in javascript:

```
var color = encodeURIComponent("#c2c2c2");
```

Answer (score 0):

You just need to escape the `#` in the URL with `%23`. Otherwise the server interprets it as an *anchor* (a location within the page, which the server doesn't need to worry about) instead of part of the query string. So just send it like this:

```
index.php?color=%23c2c2c2
```

Or you could always send it without the `#` if it's unambiguous that it should be there.

Answer (score 0):

It should work fine. Here is tested code:

```
<?php

echo "<div style='background-color: {$_GET['color']};padding: 1em; margin-bottom: 1em; '>";

echo $_GET['color'];   

echo "</div>";

?>

<form action="" method="get">

  <label>Color:</label>
    <input type="text" id="color" name="color" value="<?php echo $_GET['color']; ?>" />

    <input type="submit" value="Show Color" /> 
</form>
```

Notice no need to decode or encode anything. The browser handles encoding and PHP knows to decode.

If the concern is how to manually create the URL, that would require an alternative approach. You could consider allowing color to be the hex value without the hash mark and testing if it's a valid color value with:

```
 $valid_color = (ctype_xdigit($_GET['color'] && strlen($_GET['color']) < 7);
 if($valid_color) $color = "#" . $_GET['color'];
```